# Segfaults when declare/define a function returning a valarray with auto return type

Tags: c++, auto, c++14

Can somebody please help me to understand why the following code segfaults?  The code works if I declare/define `mk` to return `std::valarray<int>`.  I guess I am not quite sure what `auto` does here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>
auto mk(int x)
{
    return x * std::valarray<int>{1};
}
int main()
{
    auto v = mk(3);
    std::cout << v[0] << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: The code also works without `x *` part in the function `mk`.

Comment: This exact code compiled and ran fine with gcc c++11. It did warn me about the return type though.

Comment: It does compile with g++ v4.9.2 with c++14, but not with c++11.  Without optimization, it prints out `32767`.  With `-O2` it does print out `3`.  Compiled with clang++ v3.5.1, it always segfaults.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::valarray` uses expression templates.  Expression templates do not play well with return type deduction.

In this case, `x*std::valarray<int>{1}` returns an expression that says "multiply `x` by some `std::valarray<int>`.  By the time you use the object outside of `mk`, both `x` and the `std::valarray<int>` have fallen out of scope.

It then tries to use those objects (after they have expired): which in your test, a segfault results.  Classic undefined behavior.

It doesn't make a copy of its arguments, because expression templates are efficient by avoiding doing exactly that.  The cost is that they play poorly with `auto`.

There are some proposals to add something equivalent to `operator auto` -- the type that should be deduced when you want to persistently store, or return, an instance of a type -- to make expression templates more transparent.  If such a proposal where to go forward, then the expression template would say "store me a as a `valarray`" somehow.  I do not know the current state of such proposals.

Comment: The output of `typeid(v).name()` is quite insightful here. I just tried it with gcc-4.9.2. For the `auto` version, it is `St5_ExprISt8_BinClosISt12__multipliesSt9_ConstantSt9_ValArrayiiEiE1970481344`. For the one with the explicit return type, `St8valarrayIiE3`.